# Dapr not running in stand alone mode

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dapr

I am pulling my hair out trying to get a basic ASP.NET Core API working with Dapr locally.  I have followed the docs and still no luck.  I'm sure I'm just missing something basic, but I just can't work it out.

These are the steps I have done so far to try and get this working:

1. Installed Dapr CLI (cli version 0.11.0)
2. Executed `dapr init --runtime-version 1.0.0-rc.3` (3 docker containers installed and running)
3. Navigated to my dotnet project and executed the following command - `dapr run --app-id microservicea --app-port 5000 --dapr-http-port 55000 --dapr-grpc-port 55001 -- dotnet run`

After executing the `dapr run` command, the project builds and various Dapr logs appear, however, I also get the following message:

`Could not update sidecar metadata for cliPID: PUT http://127.0.0.1:55000/v1.0/metadata/cliPID giving up after 5 attempts`

This indicates to me that the sidecar is not running as a process, or just not accessible.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

As a side note, I did notice that if I matched the `dapr-http-port` to the port in the `launchsettings.json`, I get the following message - `You're up and running! Both Dapr and your app logs will appear here.`  But it still doesn't work when I try to call the `http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1.0/invoke/microservicea/method/GetSomeData` endpoint.

Some help with this would be most appreciated.  If I can't get this basic example working, then I'm going to have to abandon Dapr and look for an alternative to stitch together my microservices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was I had the wrong versions of the Dapr CLI and Runtime installed.  At the current time of writing, I made sure I had version 1.0.0-rc.3 of the CLI tool installed, and then installed version 1.0.0-rc.3 of the runtime (`dapr init --runtime-version 1.0.0-rc.3`).  Once they were installed, everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same port for `dapr-http-port` and `dapr-grpc-port`. there's bound to be a port collision there that might stop the sidecar from running.

Second, you are invoking on the wrong port. you should use `http://127.0.0.1:55000/v1.0/invoke/microservicea/method/GetSomeData`, or in this case the port you are using from launchsettings.json

Comment: Yes, good pick up about the http and grpc ports ... I've updated my question.  It turns out the issue was I had the wrong version of the CLI tool and runtime installed.  Once I had installed the correct version (1.0.0-rc.3 at this time), it all worked.